# Tengo Problemas o error con el JSON System.out: [] - type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android-studio, json, android-volley, jsonobject, jsonarray

```
I/System.out: []
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/System.out: Value [{"0":"1","cod_producto":"1","1":"Lavar y Cepillar","descripcion":"Lavar y Cepillar","2":"8.5","precio":"8.5","3":"1","cod_imagen":"1"},{"0":"2","cod_producto":"2","1":"Lavar y Cortar","descripcion":"Lavar y Cortar","2":"7.9","precio":"7.9","3":"2","cod_imagen":"2"}]
```

***at categorias_prod of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray***

Este es mi método don realizo la conexión con el web Service, al parecer si me trae el json por el run, la verdad no se en que estare fallando, alguien que me pueda orientar, se los agredecería mucho

```
 private void WEB_SERVICES_SERVICIOS_PELUQUERIA() {
        String URL_SERVICIOS_PELUQUERIA = "http://192.168.64.2/raselapp/app/Controllers/listar.php?func=liscat_prod";
               URL_SERVICIOS_PELUQUERIA.replaceAll(" ", "+");

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_SERVICIOS_PELUQUERIA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String result = jsonObject.getString("result");
                            if (result.equals("success")) {
                                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categorias_prod");
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    PeluqueriaDAO dao = new PeluqueriaDAO(
                                            obj.getString("nombre_servicio"),
                                            obj.getInt("imagen_servicio"),
                                            obj.getDouble("precio_servicio")
                                    );
                                    lista_servicios.add(dao);
                                }
                            }
                            adapter = new AdaptadorPeluqueria(lista_servicios,context);
                            recyclerViewPeluqueria.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }catch (JSONException error){
                            Toasty.error(getActivity(),"El formato de JSON esta errado",Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toasty.error(context, error.getMessage(),Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: En el codigo estas buscando "categorias_prod", pero en el json que muestras mas arriba ese campo no existe y no es un JSONARRAY. Al parecer simplemente estas intentando parcear unos datos que no coinciden con los datos que vienen en la respuesta

Comment: Estimado, gracias por la respuesta, he revisado muchas respuestas en este mismo sitio, las he implementado, pero aun asi sigue si funcionar, incluso probe el JSON online y me lo muestra bien, como puedo parsear esos datos.

Comment: Imprime cual es el valor de "response" después de esta linea public void onResponse(String response) { , agregalo a tu pregunta, eso puede responder a el problema @TonyOrmaza

Comment: Estimado, imprimí response me devuelve el Formato JSON del Web Service

Comment: No alcanza que nos digas el formato, si no podemos ver los campos que contiene, no podremos estar seguros de que este bien parseado.

Comment: {"result":"success","categorias_prod":"[{\"cod_producto\":\"1\",\"descripcion\":\"Lavar y Cepillar\",\"precio\":\"8.5\",\"cod_imagen\":\"1\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"2\",\"descripcion\":\"Lavar y Cortar\",\"precio\":\"7.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"2\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"3\",\"descripcion\":\"Planchar\",\"precio\":\"6.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"3\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"4\",\"descripcion\":\"Corte Caballero\",\"precio\":\"7.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"3\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"5\",\"descripcion\":\"Tinte, Lavar y cepillar\",\"precio\":\"33.9\"}]"}

Comment: Ese me devuelve el web services y el run de android